# How do you check if a range of times fall within another range of times?

Tags: excel-formula

Would it be possible to check if a range of times fall within another range of times? Just to provide some insight, I am building a template which calculates the premiums applicable to an employee based on their roster. The criteria are as follows:
band 1: 18:00 - 22:00
band 2: 22:00 - 06:00

The issue i am encountering is that if I input a start and end time of say 19:00 and 04:00 respectively, all 9 hours are being counted as part of band 2 instead of 3 hours in band 1 and 6 hours in band 2.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. "Roster" and "band" are undefined, but I'm not sure they even matter. What formula are you using on what input (in what cells), what output are you getting from that formula, and what output are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, times are actually stored as a fraction of a day. 6am is stored as 0.25, because it's one quarter of the way through the day. This means we can just compare times like comparing numbers.

If you have a Start Time in cell A1, you can use this formula to determine whether it falls in band 1 or band 2:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=18/24,A1<22/24),"Band 1", IF(OR(A1<6/24,A1>=22/24),"Band 2","Neither"))
```

It just checks whether it is between 6pm and 10pm for band 1, or whether it is before 6am or after 10pm for band 2.

Similarly, you can use this formula to determine whether an End Time stored in B2 falls in band 1 or band 2:

```
=IF(AND(B1>18/24,B1<=22/24),"Band 1", IF(OR(B1<=6/24,B1>22/24),"Band 2","Neither"))
```

There is a slight difference between the formulas to handle someone starting/finishing at 10pm. If they're starting at 10pm, you want to count them in band 2. However, if they're finishing at 10pm, you want to count them in band 1. The different formulas just put 10pm into the different bands accordingly.